# How to get from SED to mag [AB]?

Tags: astropy

NGC 5406 has the following mag in SIMBAD g (AB) 13.104, r (AB) 12.215, i (AB) 11.803
I wrote a little python snippet to fetch the spectrum of NGC 5406 and compute the mags, but I've hit a wall. I'm getting different values and I think it has something to do with instrumental vs calibrated magnitudes but I'm not sure.

Here is the code:

```
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord
from astropy import coordinates as coords
from astroquery.simbad import Simbad
from astroquery.sdss import SDSS
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from astropy import units as u
from spextra import Spextrum
from synphot import SourceSpectrum, Empirical1D
from synphot import units as units
import numpy as np
```

Get the coords and fetch the spectra

```
galaxy = SkyCoord.from_name("NGC5406")
pos = coords.SkyCoord(galaxy.ra, galaxy.dec, frame='icrs')
xid = SDSS.query_region(pos,spectro=True)
print(xid)
spectra = SDSS.get_spectra(matches=xid)
```

Data is in here

```
spectra_data = spectra[0][1].data
```

Wave in AA and Flux in nanomaggy

```
wave = 10**spectra_data['loglam']
flux_nanomaggy = spectra_data['flux']
```

Convert nanomaggy to FLAM

```
to_FLAM = (3.631e-6 * u.Jy).to(u.erg / u.cm**2 / u.s / u.AA, equivalencies=u.spectral_density(wave * u.AA))
flux_flam = spectra_data['flux'] * to_FLAM
```

Use speXtra library to make a spectrum object from the wave and flux arrays

```
sp = Spextrum.from_arrays(waves=wave,flux=flux_flam, flux_unit=units.FLAM)
```

Make an observation with g,r,i filtes and get the mags

```
gMag = sp.get_magnitude(filter_curve="./filters_ascii/SLOAN_SDSS.g.dat", system_name="AB")
rMag = sp.get_magnitude(filter_curve="./filters_ascii/SLOAN_SDSS.r.dat", system_name="AB")
iMag = sp.get_magnitude(filter_curve="./filters_ascii/SLOAN_SDSS.i.dat", system_name="AB")
print(f'g mag:{gMag}, r mag: {rMag}, i mag: {iMag}')
```

Results:

```
g mag:18.747706539101564 mag(AB), r mag: 16.565777072614736 mag(AB), i mag: 16.588555150926215 mag(AB)
```

Expected:

```
g (AB) 13.104, r (AB) 12.215, i (AB) 11.803
```

You can get the filter transmission profile from here [Filters](http://svo2.cab.inta-csic.es/theory/fps/index.php?id=SLOAN/SDSS.g&&mode=search&search_facility=SLOAN&search_text=SDSS#filter)